# Strip line break and empty tags from string and create array using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a very strange string coming as a response from an api. The string has many line breaks, empty p tags and other tags including img tags.

I want to write regex to strip all the line break and empty p tags and create array off the content of non empty p tags and image tags.

The sample string is the following:

```
'<p>↵   This is the cap you unscrew to open when you refuel your car↵</p>↵↵<p>↵ New line↵</p>↵↵<p>↵ <img alt="blah" src="https://www.imgone.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />↵</p>Random Text <img alt="blah" src="https://www.imgtwo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />'
```

I am looking to write a regex which will produce something like

```
['This is the cap you unscrew to open when you refuel your car', 'New line', 'Random Text']

['<img alt="blah" src="https://www.imgone.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />', '<img alt="blah" src="https://www.imgtwo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />']
```

Thank you so much for you time.

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5980430)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML string can be parsed using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) :

```js
var html = '<p>\n   This is the cap you unscrew to open when you refuel your car\n</p>\n\n<p>\n New line\n</p>\n\n<p>\n <img alt="blah" src="https://www.imgone.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />\n</p>Random Text <img alt="blah" src="https://www.imgtwo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />'

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

var lines = doc.documentElement.textContent.trim().split(/\s*\n\s*/);

var images = [].map.call(doc.images, function(img) { return img.outerHTML; });

console.log( lines );
console.log( images );
```

Comment: Thank Slai, Thats very impressive. its working fine. Only problem is that the image tag on the array is without a proper closing tag. Now it is only > instead of />

Comment: @Prabs oh you mean the resulting array. Yes, it is not the original string, but the parsed one. The original string can be retrieved with RegExp, but it won't be 100% accurate because of many edge cases